# When sharing a site or link to individual people on Linkedin, the Link doesn't show in the Linkedin Android app

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I'm currently working on putting a share button for Linkedin on a site. Everything works except when I try to share it to individual people ([Share to individual people screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XICrb.png)) with the share url (*https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=MYURL*) and they look at it
through the android app. On android the message "ME thought you might be
interested" shows in the message box but there is no link to the site. I
also tried to do the same with the share link generator (https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/share) to see if i generated a wrong link but that causes the same problem. I have tested with the IOS app as well and there the links does show and work. Is anybody else having the same issue and knows what is going wrong and how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: share your code with question

Comment: I use  a customized url like https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=MYURL as a link to share the webpage. (Docs: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
Intent linkedinIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
linkedinIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, edinputText.getText().toString().trim());
linkedinIntent.setType("text/plain");

boolean linkedinAppFound = false;
List<ResolveInfo> matches2 = this.getPackageManager()
                        .queryIntentActivities(linkedinIntent, 0);

for (ResolveInfo info : matches2) {
     if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith(
                            "com.linkedin")) {
     linkedinIntent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
     linkedinAppFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
      }
    if (linkedinAppFound) {
           startActivity(linkedinIntent);
      } else {

           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please install the LinkedIn app to share your result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```